# Java 8 modify stream elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wanted to write pure function with Java 8 that would take a collection as an argument, apply some change to every object of that collection and return a new collection after the update. I want to follow FP principles so I dont want to update/modify the collection that was passed as an argument.

Is there any way of doing that with Stream API without creating a copy of the original collection first (and then using forEach or 'normal' for loop)?

Sample object below and lets assume that I want to append a text to one of the object property:

```
public class SampleDTO {
    private String text;
}
```

So I want to do something similar to below, but without modifying the collection. Assuming "list" is a `List<SampleDTO>`.

```
list.forEach(s -> {
    s.setText(s.getText()+"xxx");
});
```

Comment: I'd say that this does go a little against the principle of functional programming here. The idea is to not mutate state, but create new state as a product of the function. That's why, instead of mutating the original list, you should be using the `map` function provided by the Java stream API to create a new list.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You must have some method/constructor that generates a copy of an existing `SampleDTO` instance, such as a copy constructor.

Then you can `map` each original `SampleDTO` instance to a new `SampleDTO` instance, and `collect` them into a new `List` :

```
List<SampleDTO> output = 
    list.stream()
        .map(s-> {
                     SampleDTO n = new SampleDTO(s); // create new instance
                     n.setText(n.getText()+"xxx"); // mutate its state
                     return n; // return mutated instance
                 })
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer helped me solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967184/convert-one-class-object-into-another-using-stream :)

Answer (score 5):

To make this more elegant way I would suggest create a `Method` with in the class.

```
 public class SampleDTO {
 private String text;
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public SampleDTO(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public SampleDTO getSampleDTO() {
    this.setText(getText()+"xxx");
    return this;
}
    }
```

and add it like:

```
List<SampleDTO> output =list.stream().map(SampleDTO::getSampleDTO).collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks for the comment and downvote . I have fixed this . now it will compile

Comment: I downvoted because your answer had 1 vote and I wanted to promote other answers which were correct, sorry if that was too harsh. Now that you have corrected it, I have not only reverted my downvote but also upvoted.

Comment: However, now the original object is modified, and OP wanted to not mutate neither the original list nor its elements. You should consider creating a copy of the original object with its text attribute modified.

Comment: The method getSampleDTO modifying its text? Vary bad naming of the method and very nasty side-effect

Answer (score 5):

I think a cleaner and more readable solution is:

```
List<SampleDTO> unmodifiable = Arrays.asList(new SampleDTO("1"), new SampleDTO("2"));

List<SampleDTO> modified = unmodifiable.stream()
            .map(s -> new SampleDTO(s.getText())) // '.map(SampleDTO::new)' with copy constructor
            .peek(s -> s.setText(s.getText() + "xxx"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you have copy constructor of SampleDTO you can replace `map` function with `.map(SampleDTO::new)`.

`peek` function will provide action on elements of Stream without changing result type of Stream.

Comment: Note: You should not use peek() in production code. Only for debugging.

Comment: peek() is not quite intended to be used to change stream elements (although it surely can, and, according to documentation, "exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline"

Comment: @ghost28147 it means that 'peek' is lazy method which can't be executed for all elements in stream, for example when you use method 'findFirst' (you can find first element in stream and 'peek' will not be executed for other elements), but if you use it before 'collect' method, which means that all your elements will be used for inserting in collection, you can use 'peek'.

In general you can use 'peek' method if you know how streams work inside.
Docs says "mainly to support debugging", not "must't be used in production".

Comment: @alex87 see my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Streams are immutable like strings so you cannot get around needing to create a new stream/list/array

That being said you can use .Collect() to return a new collection post change so

```
List<Integer> result = inList.stream().map().Collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better, especially if doing multi-threaded work, to stream the original list into a new modified list or whatever else is desired.

The new list or map or whatever other structure you desire can be created as part of the streaming process.

When the streaming process is completed, simply swap the original with the new.

All of this should occur in a synchronized block.

In this manner, you get the maximum performance and parallelism for the reduce or whatever it is you are doing, and finish with an atomic swap.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lombok, you can use immutable setters.

```
.map(s -> s.withText(s.getText() + "..."))
```

See: https://projectlombok.org/features/With

Comment: Damn, I like that!