# How would I express this operation using streams in java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an class which has an implementable method from double[] to double[]

```
class MyClass{
    public abstract double[] myMethod(double[] input);
}
```

And somewhere else in my code theres a list of myClass with different implementations of MyClass

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
fill(myList);
```

I then want to write a method which takes this list and a double[] as input and returns the repeated application of myMethod

```
public double[] repeatedApplication(ArrayList<MyClass> myList, double[] input){
    double[] output = input;
    for(MyClass myObject : myList)
        output = myObject.myMethod(output);
    return output;
}
```

How would I go about implementing repeatedAplication using java streams

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 modify stream elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302531/java-8-modify-stream-elements)

Comment: In your own method `repeatedApplication` you only will return the `double[]` result of the last element of the list. Is this what you want?

Comment: @cyberbrain no, `output` is reused inside each iteration: the input of an iteration is the output of the previous one.

Comment: @sp00m you are right. I leave my comment so that others don't read the code wrong as I did ;)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't use a parallel stream, the following reduction-based approach should do:

```java
public static double[] repeatedApplication(ArrayList<MyClass> myList, double[] input){
    return myList.stream().reduce(input, (doubles, myClass) -> myClass.myMethod(doubles), (x, y) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not have been called");
    });
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-, which example is very close to yours.